# troubles getting data from a rest api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

hi im learning react native with axios to consume a rest api made on php, so im trying that when my fucntion pass some values to the api it should give me back the result of a the opeartion.

y have tried some things like i do the login or save values so i thought it would be the same thing, but it doesnt work

this is my api code force.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

//export default axios.create({
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://exitusdesarrollo.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com/AppForceControllers/controllers'
});
```

this is how i think im sending the vlaues to the api

```
const getRFC = dispatch => async ({ vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate }) => {
  try {
    const response = await ForceApi.get(
      '/GetRfcController.php',
      { vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate },
    );
    dispatch({ type: 'rfc', payload: response.data.resultRFC });
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch({
      type: 'add_error',
      payload: 'Error de Conexion'
    });
  }
};
```

this is my api instructions

Rute : 
http://exitusdesarrollo.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com/AppForceControllers/controllers/GetRfcController.php

Recive on body

```
{
  "vLastName": "IBARRA",
  "vSecondLastName": "CRESPO",
  "vName": "ALFREDO",
  "vSecondName": "",
  "vBirthDate": "08/02/1991"
}
```

Response

```
{
  "error": false,
  "resultRFC": "IACA910208HQ1"
}
```

when i do this it only show a yellow warning 
one saying "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0); undefined is not an object

any help or orientation would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there any error, since you are getting response i am little confused, can you explain whats actually the issue

Comment: Sounds like a linter or react warning. Can you share more of that warning? Does it provide any bit of a stack trace?

Comment: yeahm the problema is that when i run my app, teres is a warning that says 
" yellow warning one saying "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0); undefined is not an object".  That and the fact that i dont get the answer of the calculus

Comment: try adding a return after the try dispatch line , let me know if it fixed for you

Comment: and i think one more issue since its because you are not using https !!

Comment: check both and let me know what was the issue !

Comment: the problem of the warnings seemed to be the way i was calling the function getrfc, butn now whenever i type on one input it throwsme the next error:

unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.vName')

Comment: i did 2 console logs, one that prints each one of the variables like vName and when i write something in the input it Works, but when i tried to consol log the function getRFC it just throws me undefineds

Comment: @ignos555 Can you update your question with the component code calling/logging `getRFC`?